# Logging with multiple parameters

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I am currently working on a program wherein, I must write all output to a log file.

I need to write a log method, that should give an output with a level, a message, an object value, another message, an integer value, another message and another integer value, in the same order as I have specified. I can't seem to find a log method that does this. I am using `Java.util.logging`. Is this possible?

Comment: Consider Log4J http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

Comment: @verbose-mode Why? java util logging does all that is required and and is simpler to use. As far as I see it your suggestion breaks the KISS (Keep it Simple S…) principle.

Answer (score 41):

I assume you need the log format in the below format
FINE,Message1,object.GetValue(),Message2,1,Message3,2

You need to create an output message format

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}",new Object[]{Message1,object.getValue(),Message2,1,Message3,2});
```

Now you need to create a custom formatter which by extending Formatter class

```
public class DataFormatter extends Formatter {

@Override
public synchronized String format(LogRecord record) {
    String formattedMessage = formatMessage(record);
    String throwable = "";
    String outputFormat = "%1$s, %2$s \n %3$s"; //Also adding for logging exceptions
    if (record.getThrown() != null) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        pw.println();
        record.getThrown().printStackTrace(pw);
        pw.close();
        throwable = sw.toString();
    }
    return String.format(outputFormat,record.getLevel().getName(),formattedMessage,throwable);
}
}
```

Now set the newly created formatter

```
    for(int i=0;i<logger.getHandlers().length;i++)
        logger.getHandlers()[i].setFormatter(new DataFormatter());
```

Comment: logger.info("Logging with  id  {} and cache : {} " ,id,cache );

Comment: This answer is correct. I have achieved the same by using `java.util.logging.Logger`'s method `public void log(Level level, String msg, Object params[])`. You just need to number the placeholders in the message like `{0}`, `{1}`, etc. and pass an array of parameters like shown above `new Object[] {parameter1, parameter2}`.

Answer (score 38):

We used below code while using slf4j logger -

```
logger.error("Error while finding A from DB. a : {} and b : {}", a, b);
logger.info("Nothing found in db for A with a : {} and b : {}", a, b);
```

Comment: has there anything changed, it doesnt work for me.

e.g:    LOGGER.info("Nothing found in db for A with a : {} and b : {}",target, file.getName());

Comment: this works: 
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"Added file  to the target: {0}", target);

but not with multiple params

Comment: Question was about `java.util.logging`.

Answer (score 21):

It's a quite old topic, anyhow, my two cents, because I also prefer to use java.util.logging.Logger` in my projects where sufficient.

Lambdas make this boilerplate Formatter extension for multiple custom parameters more or less obsolete, unless you benefit from its application-wide reuse. In (my) simple scenarios, log messages are tailored to the code part where it is inserted, so `String.format()` is usually much easier and more flexible.

**Before Java 8** and lambdas, the `Formatter` was the only possibility to postpone the message construction. The only *alternative* was, to construct the message to log in advance before the `loggable` check based on the Level took place.
**With Java 8 lambdas**, the String formatting can be postponed to after the `loggable` check, but still with access to the original method context. The only small downside is, that all accessed fields need to be final, due to the lambda restrictions.

Here a fairly simple snippet:

```
final String val1 = "lambda expression log message";
final Level level = Level.INFO;
Logger.getGlobal().log(level, () -> 
        String.format("Hello, I'm a %s, evaluated after %s loggable check.", val1, level)
);
Logger.getGlobal().log(level, new RuntimeException(), () -> 
        String.format("Hello, I'm a %s with a stack trace, evaluated after %s loggable check.", val1, level)
);
```

Hope this helps some of you who also want to use the built-in logging :-)

Cheers Ben

Comment: Disadvantage of this is that parameter formatting cannot be applied when they are inserted through `String.format` rather than `java.util.logging.Logger` itself.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example that works for me:

```
Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("MyLogger");
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, "Test {0}, {1}", new Object[]{2, 3});
```

Result:

```
INFO: Test 2, 3
```